# Do not wrap text in ActionBar navigation tabs Android 4.x

Tags: text, tabs, android-actionbar, word-wrap

I am using ActionBar.Tabs (4.x), and if I have a bit longer text in the caption, it is wrapped to 2 lines, just in the middle of the word.

Like:
text = ABCDEF
on the tab:

> ABCDE
>
> F

This is very ugly.
[See screenshot](http://www.shareimage.org/images/zzdapdvz8yltn3pt7dg.jpg)

How can I prevent the ActionBar.Tabs to wrap the text, and make the tabs wider instead?
Thanks

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?  I'm having the same problem.  Tabs are showing on the left half of the bar and action buttons are showing on the right.  I'd like to give the tabs more room to avoid wrapping, and show fewer action buttons before the overflow.